# Multiple checked boxes in a checkbox using Jquery and loading into a div

Tags: php, jquery, checkbox

I have some checkboxes and I would like to allow multiple selections, only that after each selection a DIV would loading the content.

Here is my checkbox that comes from a PHP while:

```
<input type='checkbox' class='regularCheckbox' name='color[]' value='".$colorBoxes[color_base1]."' />
```

Here is my current Jquery which only allows me 1 checked box:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("input:checkbox").change(function() {
        if($(this).is(':checked')) 
            {
        $(".loadingItems").fadeIn(300); //fade in on change
        var color = $(this).val();
            $(".indexMain").load('indexMain.php?color='+color,function(){
            $(".indexMain").fadeIn(slow);

            })
            $(".loadingItems").fadeOut(300); //remove when load is complete
        }
        else 
            {
$(".indexMain").load('indexMain.php');
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be better served in your case to use `delegate` instead of `change`:

`$(document).delegate("input:checkbox", "change", function(evt) { //... });`

Comment: the `.delegate` method will attach the event handler to all present *and* future elements which match the selector. If you are adding and removing checkboxes dynamically, it thus ensure that your handler executes for all of them.

Comment: ´$(document).delegate("input:checkbox", "change", function(){
  if($(this).is(':checked')) 
   {
     $(".loadingItems").fadeIn(300); //fade in on change
        var color = $(this).val();
   $(".indexMain").load('indexMain.php?color='+color,function(){
   $(".indexMain").fadeIn(slow);
   
   })
            $(".loadingItems").fadeOut(300); //remove when load is complete
        }
  else 
   {
   $(".loadingItems").fadeIn(300); //fade in on change
$(".indexMain").load('indexMain.php');
               $(".loadingItems").fadeOut(300); //remove when load is complete
   }
  });´ // Not working...